# Create a List or Install a List?

Tags: custom-list

Which word do you recommend I use in a tutorial for SharePoint 2013 and lists.

Should I write "create a list", or "install a list"? Or does it matter?

Comment: "Add a list app" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Create" is more accurate. The list template is already 'Installed' if you can see it. Technically, in SP2013, they now call a List an App, or more recently an Add-In. In the Cog wheel, you'll see 'Add an App' from which you can create a Custom List